# Only ONE Outlook 2010 installation "Cannot connect to Exchange server" when setting up new profile

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, exchange-2010

I have a single server Exchange 2010 installation - OWA Connectivity has been confirmed, Autodiscover is configured and working properly for EVERY other installation. Other user accounts tested on problem Outlook, none can connect. Windows Firewall is pre-configured by Group Policy, only modifications being related to remote management. Firewall has also been disabled during diagnostic period. Network discovery and file sharing is enabled on workstation as well. Windows 7 Professional, latest updates installed.

Driving me nuts. Help, serverfault?

*bump*

Comment: Why do people always say "not best practice, I know"? When in fact, that statement is very often taken out of context. A single server installation is perfectly acceptable and would be considered best practice in a small environment such as yours. Microsoft doesn't expect every company to be able to implement separate CAS, Hub Transport, Mailbox, etc. servers. Small Business Server combines all of these roles on a single server and is considered best practice if it fits the business needs, budget, requirements, limitations, etc.

Comment: The fact that you can install all of the Exchange roles on a single server should intuitively imply that it's a perfectly acceptable, supported configuration under the right circumstances and in the right environment.

Comment: I know they don't expect it, but they also don't hesitate to mention that the greater the separation of roles, the better. *shrug* I just didn't wanna catch any s**t for it, and I did anyways. lol.

Comment: @JohnThePro - There's nothing that says this isn't best practice, so I took that out of your question. My Exchange 2010 runs on a single server (as did my Exchange 2003) and it runs quite happily, and it's totally supported by Microsoft should I have the need.

Comment: @JohnThePro: No offense, of course, with either of my comments. :)

Comment: @joe, of course not! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what really happened.

There was a bug in Update Rollup 5, prior to SP1 that was causing this issue to occur. After applying SP1 and subsequent updates to Exchange, the issue went away, and has not cropped up again.

Answer (score 0):

My comments aside, this definitely appears to be a workstation problem. Any chance of wiping this workstation and starting from scratch?

Comment: This workstation actually is actually a new image, freshly made. The developer is already working on the machine, and I'd hate to put him through more downtime.

Comment: @JohnThePro - does right clicking the Outlook icon in the system tray and selecting **Test Autoconfiguration status** give you anything interesting? I know you said you already configured it, but just verify that tools output.

Comment: What's your imaging process\product? Are you using Sysprep or WAIK?

Comment: Sysprep. I used WAIK to make my PE CD, but Sysprep to wrap it all up. In regards to the Test settings on right-click, Outlook won't run because I haven't finalized a profile.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check **((Assuming you're already discarded connectivity issues: access to exchange, test port with telnet))**:

- Test **Autodiscover** on the troubled host, here's an offline [tool](http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-03-34-95-63/AutodiscoverTest.zip) for that (read more [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/provtest/archive/2010/08/13/exchange-server-2010-sp1-beta-hosting-deployment-part-9-autodiscover.aspx)).
- **DNS** (Flush your DNS (ipconfig /flushdns, /registerdns).
- You say the machine is getting settings from **GPOs**, I'd be tempted to do a result and cross reference with another working machine... also check the OU this machine was added to (Not sure specifically how this would matter to you though, you're going to have to assess what settings the machine is supposed to be getting).
- There is no real good way (that I know) to be 100% that your Outlook client is installed properly.  I'd also be tempted to **repair the install**, or even uninstall and re-install outlook.

Don't you love it when similarly (or identically) configured machines, that are supposed to work the same, somehow don't?... Well, the nice thing is that you have a known working configuration, and this box's issue just happens to be an anomaly.  Remember to reboot a few times after forcing a *gpupdate*, if you're needing to fix GP settings, or repairing the software... or try a new user in case this user's profile is corrupt somehow.

Comment: I'll be sure to check out that offline tool tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, ran the offline tool, from the affected machine, and it discovered all necessary Autodiscover information without issue. Attempted a "Repair" of Outlook information, rebooted, tried again, no progress. I am now uninstalling Office, will flush DNS and force GP update, reboot, and then reinstall.

Comment: ....and none of this helped. Starting to think it might be that specific users' profile.

Comment: I almost suggested that, but read the questions wrong the first time.  It would make sense to try a different profile on that computer.

Comment: Interesting update.... now it seems that any new connections from Outlook don't seem to be able to find the server. I now have 2 machines stricken.

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing this error message are you?

> An unknown error occurred, error code: 0x80070057
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028193

Even though the hotfix description mentions Outlook 2010 connecting to Exchange 2003, I had the exact same issue a few weeks ago on a brand new Windows 7 install, with Office 2010 Home & Business installed - connecting to a SBS2011 server (Exchange 2010). The profile setup wizard at first-run would just bomb out with an error.

I ended up creating the profile manually through Control Panel/Mail, and chose to specify server settings manually.